# dotnet test /p option not supported when using a dll path

Tags: .net-core, dotnetcorecli

I have a dotnet core project that I have already compiled:

```
> dotnet build --configuration Release
```

If I try to run the test using the resulting dll using the `/p` option, it fails:

```
> dotnet test .\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\MyProject.dll /p:CollectCoverage=true
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.10.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The argument /p:CollectCoverage=true is invalid. Please use the /help option to check the list of valid arguments.
```

Does anybody know how I could pass the /p option when providing a dll?

Note that I know that I could use the `--no-build` option like this:

```
> dotnet test --configuration Release --no-build /p:CollectCoverage=true
```

Unfortunately, for some reasons that would be too long to explain here, I can't use that option. I really have to call `dotnet test` by providing a **path** to an already existing dll.